# Find Maximal Eigenvalue of Matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the Maximal Eigenvalue of the matrix $A^{100}$ where 
$$A =\left(\begin{matrix}
  1/6 & 0 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\
 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/3 
\end{matrix}\right)$$
I know how to find the eigenvalue of the matrix but how would I do it to the $100$th power. Would I find the eigenvalue of this matrix and take that value and take it to the $100$th power?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Correct (but be careful about signs).

Comment: Please use Latex next time

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is diagonizable you are right.

Comment: Observe that this matrix is stochastic. That should give you a short-cut to the solution.

Comment: @sbkldskl4 In addition to amd's answer. Your matrix is from a regular Markov Chain, and so the dominant eigenvalue is $1$. So raising your matrix to the power 100 still results in $1$ for that eigenvalue